# How do I capture an endless network stream and filter out metadata in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, icecast, shoutcast

I'm writing an app for a radio station in Germany and I want to get the audio stream title informations from their Icecast server. How do I receive the audio stream in Flutter/Dart and filter out the audio metadata for displaying the song name?

I've already got the code for getting the `icy-metaint` number, needed to count the bytes (mp3 audio data) up to the byte showing how long the metadata string is. (In my case, it's 16000)

My code for getting the `icy-metaint` integer:

```
Future<Map> getInfoDataFromIceCastStream(String url) async {
    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));
    request.headers['Icy-MetaData'] = '1';
    var response = await request.send();
    var headers = response.headers;

    return headers;
  }

  Future<int> getIcyMetaInt(String url) async {
    Map metaData = await getInfoDataFromIceCastStream(url);
    print(metaData['icy-metaint']);
    return int.parse(metaData['icy-metaint']);
  }
```

In the end, I expect to get a string like:
`StreamTitle='Gong 96.3 - Mark Forster - Chöre';StreamUrl='';`

Comment: did you get a solution for this, I am also having the problem to get stream title, url... in flutter?

Comment: In my case, I'm looking for how to save a part of stream radio.